# Logstash opening thousands of ports when capturing syslog via UDP 514

Tags: port, logstash, syslog, time-wait

I have recently started using Logstash to capture syslog data from from the default UDP 514 port. The program runs correctly and gives me the data I am looking for, however, looking in netstat during runtime, it opens thousands of ports on the server and leaves them in TIME_WAIT status. This is rather strange. I have looked online but have not been able to find an explanation for this.

Another interesting thing is, all those ports seem to be opened by the Windows kernel, PID 0, but they do in fact correspond to the Logstash process because they only appear when it runs, and disappear a few minutes after closing Logstash.

So my question is, why is this happening, and what can be done to prevent Logstash opening all those ports?

I have included a screenshot of Netstat output when Logstash is running, and my configuration file below.

[image]

```
  # LogStash configuration file, to read syslog messages from a port and write them to CSV files.
input {
    # Read from standard UDP syslog port.
    udp {
        port => 514
        }
}
filter {
    # Look for records having specific formats.
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} %{WORD:direction} %{WORD:protocol} %{WORD:object} %{NUMBER} for %{NOTSPACE:label_from}:%{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1} \(%{IP:ip_from_2}/%{NUMBER:port_from_2}\)\(%{WORD:domain_from}\\%{NOTSPACE:user_from}\) to %{NOTSPACE:label_to}:%{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1} \(%{IP:ip_to_2}/%{NUMBER:port_to_2}\) \(%{NOTSPACE:user_to}\)" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} %{WORD:direction} %{WORD:protocol} %{WORD:object} %{NUMBER} for %{NOTSPACE:label_from}:%{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1} \(%{IP:ip_from_2}/%{NUMBER:port_from_2}\) to %{NOTSPACE:label_to}:%{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1} \(%{IP:ip_to_2}/%{NUMBER:port_to_2}\)" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} %{WORD:direction} %{WORD:protocol} %{WORD:object} %{NUMBER} for %{NOTSPACE:label_from}:%{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1} to %{NOTSPACE:label_to}:%{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1}" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} %{WORD:protocol} %{WORD:object} %{NUMBER} for %{NOTSPACE:label_from}:%{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1}\(%{NOTSPACE:login_from}\) to %{NOTSPACE:label_to}:%{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1} duration %{NOTSPACE:duration} bytes %{NUMBER:bytes}( \(%{NOTSPACE:login_to}\))?" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} %{WORD:protocol} %{WORD:object} %{NUMBER} for %{NOTSPACE:label_from}:%{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1} to %{NOTSPACE:label_to}:%{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1} duration %{NOTSPACE:duration} bytes %{NUMBER:bytes}" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} dynamic %{WORD:protocol} %{WORD:object} from %{NOTSPACE:label_from}:%{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1} to %{NOTSPACE:label_to}:%{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1}( duration %{NOTSPACE:duration})?" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} %{WORD:protocol} src %{NOTSPACE:label_from}:%{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1} dst %{NOTSPACE:label_to}:%{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1}( by access-group \"%{WORD:access_group}\")?" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action}( %{WORD:direction})? %{WORD:protocol} %{WORD:object} for faddr %{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1} gaddr %{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1} laddr %{IP:ip_to_2}/%{NUMBER:port_to_2}" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} %{WORD:protocol} \(no connection\) from %{IP:ip_from_1}/%{NUMBER:port_from_1} to %{IP:ip_to_1}/%{NUMBER:port_to_1}" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{NOTSPACE} %{NOTSPACE:access_list_name} %{WORD:action} %{WORD:protocol} %{NOTSPACE:label_from}/%{IP:ip_from_1}\(%{NUMBER:port_from_1}\) -> %{NOTSPACE:label_to}/%{IP:ip_to_1}\(%{NUMBER:port_to_1}\) %{GREEDYDATA} \[%{GREEDYDATA}\]" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:action} local-host %{NOTSPACE:label_from}:%{IP:ip_from_1}( duration %{NOTSPACE:duration})?" }
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{WORD:protocol} %{WORD:object} %{WORD:action} from %{IP:ip_from_1}(/%{NUMBER:port_from_1})? to %{NOTSPACE:label_to}:%{IP:ip_to_1}(/%{NUMBER:port_to_1})?" }

        add_tag => [ "matched" ]
    }
    # If message doesn't match one of the fully-specified formats, try matching against an unparsed syslog format.
    if "matched" not in [tags] {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGPROG}: %{GREEDYDATA:message_text}" }
            add_tag => [ "matched" ]
        }
    }
    # If message still doesn't match, just grab the whole thing.
    if "matched" not in [tags] {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:message_text}" }
        }
    }
    # Try deriving geographic coordinates from the IP addresses, using the LogStash built-in GeoIP database.
    geoip {
        source => "ip_from_1"
        target => "geoip_from_1"
#       add_field => [ "[geoip_from_1][latitude]", "%{[geoip_from_1][latitude]}"  ]
#       add_field => [ "[geoip_from_1][longitude]", "%{[geoip_from_1][longitude]}" ]
    }
    geoip {
        source => "ip_from_2"
        target => "geoip_from_2"
#       add_field => [ "[geoip_from_2][latitude]", "%{[geoip_from_2][latitude]}"  ]
#       add_field => [ "[geoip_from_2][longitude]", "%{[geoip_from_2][longitude]}" ]
    }
    geoip {
        source => "ip_to_1"
        target => "geoip_to_1"
#       add_field => [ "[geoip_to_1][latitude]", "%{[geoip_to_1][latitude]}"  ]
#       add_field => [ "[geoip_to_1][longitude]", "%{[geoip_to_1][longitude]}" ]
    }
    geoip {
        source => "ip_to_2"
        target => "geoip_to_2"
#       add_field => [ "[geoip_to_2][latitude]", "%{[geoip_to_2][latitude]}"  ]
#       add_field => [ "[geoip_to_2][longitude]", "%{[geoip_to_2][longitude]}" ]
    }
    # Convert geographic coordinates from text to numeric.
#   mutate {
#       convert => [ "[geoip_from_1][latitude]", "float"]
#       convert => [ "[geoip_from_1][longitude]", "float"]
#       convert => [ "[geoip_from_2][latitude]", "float"]
#       convert => [ "[geoip_from_2][longitude]", "float"]
#       convert => [ "[geoip_to_1][latitude]", "float"]
#       convert => [ "[geoip_to_1][longitude]", "float"]
#       convert => [ "[geoip_to_1][latitude]", "float"]
#       convert => [ "[geoip_to_2][longitude]", "float"]
#   }
    # Replace the LogStash event timestamp with the value from the message.
    date {
        match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
    }
}
output {
    # Write parsed fields to a CSV file, using a new file every minute (so that files can be loaded quickly into the data warehouse).
    csv {
        fields => ["@timestamp", "host", "program", "action", "direction", "protocol", "object", "label_from", "ip_from_1", "port_from_1", "user_from", "[geoip_from_1][country_code3]", "[geoip_from_1][city_name]", "[geoip_from_1][postal_code]", "[geoip_from_1][latitude]", "[geoip_from_1][longitude]", "ip_from_2", "port_from_2", "[geoip_from_2][country_code3]", "[geoip_from_2][city_name]", "[geoip_from_2][postal_code]", "[geoip_from_2][latitude]", "[geoip_from_2][longitude]", "label_to", "ip_to_1", "port_to_1", "user_to", "[geoip_to_1][country_code3]", "[geoip_to_1][city_name]", "[geoip_to_1][postal_code]", "[geoip_to_1][latitude]", "[geoip_to_1][longitude]", "ip_to_2", "port_to_2", "[geoip_to_2][country_code3]", "[geoip_to_2][city_name]", "[geoip_to_2][postal_code]", "[geoip_to_2][latitude]", "[geoip_to_2][longitude]", "duration", "bytes", "access_group", "message_text"]
        path => "D:\ETLFiles\IT\In\syslog_%{+YYYYMMddHHmm}.csv"
    }
}
```